# play defined area without delaying loop

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
from pyautogui import *
from threading import Timer
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con
start = time.time()

def b()
    time.sleep(0.30)
    pydirectinput.press('b')
    print("i see it")     

while True:
   if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('b.png', region=(1717,1127,150,150), grayscale=True, confidence=0.8):
        b()
else:
    print("cant see anything")
```

I'm still quite new to programming and even newer to python but I tried to get the script to detect an image, once it detects the image to play `def b()` which would press the b key after a few seconds. The only problem is, I'm trying to get the code to still search for the image while the `def b()` is still playing and to play it again if it detects that image again during that short time frame.

Comment: What you're describing is called concurrency. This may help -- https://realpython.com/courses/speed-python-concurrency/

Comment: @TeejayBruno yes that seems to have fixed it, thank you!